# How do you map data from unsorted numpy arrays to sorted ones for interpolation?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, interpolation

I have 3 numpy arrays that need sorting:

```
a = (np.random.uniform(0,1,npoints))
b = (np.random.uniform(0,1,npoints))
c = vh[1]
```

`c` is one of the coefficient modes of an SVD matrix decomposition (not important for this question). I need to perform 2-dimensional interpolation with these arrays, using `interp2d` or something similar. `a` and `b` are the inputs and `c` is the output. However, the interpolant function returns nonsense for values that are not the original values. I construct a grid using

```
sample  = 10
input_arr = list(zip(a[:sample], b[:sample]))

A= np.linspace(min(a[:sample]), max(a[:sample]))
B = np.linspace(min(b[:sample]), max(b[:sample]))
A, B = np.meshgrid(A, B)
```

And interpolate using

```
func = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(a[:sample], b[:sample], c1[:sample])
```

But this doesn't work at all, and I believe it is because the order of the elements of `c` depends on the order of `a` and `b`, which are random, but I make an interpolation with `linspace`, which is ordered. How do I sort the arrays so that I can interpolate correctly?

EDIT: full code is here

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata


def f(x, a, b):
    return a*x*x + b*x + 1

end = 1.01
begin = 0
x = np.arange(begin,end,0.1)
npoints = int(1/0.1+1)

a = (np.random.uniform(0,1,npoints))
b = (np.random.uniform(0,1,npoints))
#c = np.random.uniform(0,1,npoints)

cols = 5

y = np.zeros((cols,a.size))

for i in range(cols):
        y[i] = f(x, a[i], b[i])

u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(y, full_matrices=True)


c1 = (vh[0])
c2 = vh[1]
c3 = vh[2]

sample  = 8
input_arr = list(zip(a[:sample], b[:sample]))

A= np.linspace(min(a[:sample]), max(a[:sample]))
B = np.linspace(min(b[:sample]), max(b[:sample]))
A, B = np.meshgrid(A, B)

interp = scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator(input_arr, c1[:sample], fill_value=0)

c1_interpolated = interp(A, B)
```

Comment: Why do you construct the meshgrid in the first place? For visualisation?

Comment: Yes, well not for visualization (plotting) per se, but I need values of the function on all values of a and b on the grid, so I can compare the interpolated array to the actual array.

Comment: You don't use that anywhere in the example, which makes it quite confusing. Also, is there any direct connection of `a` and `b` to `c1`?  I mean, they are both random and if `c1` is a array of numbers you get from somewhere else, no wonder the interpolation returns random results as well.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll edit the post to reflect the full code.  a and b are input parameters for an SVD decomposition, and c1 is the coefficients of the first mode of that decomposition.